# Não mostra a saida correta

Tags: java

Eu acredito que posso ser o resultado da minha ordenação que está influenciando a saída, por ex se fosse 6 8 10 deveria mostrar TRIANGULO RETANGULO mas está mostrando TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO.

O código que fiz esta no final do enunciado

> Leia 3 números decimais A, B e C e ordeneos em ordem decrescente, de
>   modo que o lado A representa o maior dos 3 lados. A seguir, determine
>   o tipo de triângulo que estes três lados formam, com base nos
>   seguintes casos, sempre escrevendo uma mensagem adequada:
>
> se A ≥ B+C, apresente a mensagem: NAO FORMA TRIANGULO
>
> se A 2 = B 2 + C 2 , apresente a mensagem: TRIANGULO RETANGULO
>
> se A 2 > B 2 + C 2 , apresente a mensagem: TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO
>
> se A 2 < B 2 + C 2 , apresente a mensagem: TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO
>
> se os três lados forem iguais, apresente a mensagem: TRIANGULO
>   EQUILATERO
>
> se apenas dois dos lados forem iguais, apresente a mensagem:
>   TRIANGULO   ISOSCELES
>
> Ex   Entradas (A, B, C)              Saída esperada  7 5 7
>   TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO
>                                   TRIANGULO ISOSCELES   6 6 10                          TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO
>                                   TRIANGULO ISOSCELES
>
> 6 6 6                           TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO
>                                   TRIANGULO EQUILATERO
>
> 5 7 2                           NAO FORMA TRIANGULO
>
> 6 8 10                          TRIANGULO RETANGULO

Codigo

```
public class Ex18 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        double a,b,c,maior;

        System.out.printf("Digite o valor de A: ");
        a=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("Digite o valor de B: ");
        b=sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.printf("Digite o valor de C: ");
        c=sc.nextDouble();


        if(a > b){
          maior = a;
          a = b;
          b = maior;
        }if(b > c){
          maior = b;
          b = c;
          c = maior;
        }
        if(a>= c+b){
           System.out.println("NAO FORMA TRIANGULO");

        }else if((a*a) == (b*b)+(c*c)){
            System.out.println("TRIANGULO RETANGULO");

        }else if((a*a)>(b*b)+(c*c)){
            System.out.println("TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO");

        }else if((a*a)<(b*b)+(c*c)){
            System.out.println("TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO"); 

        }

        if(a >= b+c){
           System.out.println("NAO FORMA TRIANGULO");
        }else if( a == b && a == c){
            System.out.println("TRIANGULO EQUILATERO");

        }else if(a == b || b == c || c == a){
            System.out.println("TRIANGULO ISOSCELES");
        }else{
            System.out.println("");
        }


       }

    }
```

Comment: Se a=6, b=8 e c=10, ele não entra nos 2 primeiros `if`'s (`if(a > b)` e `if(b > c)`). Depois, o próximo `if` também falha (`if (a >= c + b)`), pois 6 não é maior que 8 + 10. Os dois `if`'s seguintes também falham, pois 6 ao quadrado não é maior nem igual a 8 ao quadrado mais 10 ao quadrado. Ele só vai entrar no `if` seguinte (acutangulo). O problema está em fazer com que `a` seja a hipotenusa (ou seja, a lógica dos 2 primeiros `if`'s que está errada)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, eu vou revisar a lógica.

Comment: Creio que você esteja calculando os valores com a ordenação incorreta. Esse calculo "(a*a) == (b*b)+(c*c)" é o teorema de pitagoras, por isso "a" terá que ser o maior lado (hipotenusa) e "b" e "c" serão os catetos. A ordenação correta seria decrescente: a=10, b=8 e c=6.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que achei a solução, minha ideia foi ordenar os lados em um vetor, uma vez que a biblioteca `Arrays` possui o método `sort()`, ele ordena os números do vetor em ordem decrescente.

Para que o vetor seja ordenado em ordem crescente basta multiplicar a array por -1, segue o código:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

double a,b,c,maior;

System.out.printf("Digite o valor de A: ");
a=sc.nextDouble();
System.out.printf("Digite o valor de B: ");
b=sc.nextDouble();
System.out.printf("Digite o valor de C: ");
c=sc.nextDouble();

//nomeia o vetor
//exemplo 1, 2, 3
double lados[] = {a,b,c};

//multiplica os valores por -1
//exemplo -1, -2, -3
for(int i=0;i<lados.length;i++) {
    lados[i]=-lados[i];            
}

//ordena os dados em ordem decrescente
//exemplo -3, -2, -1
Arrays.sort(lados); 

//multiplica os valores por -1 denovo
//exemplo 3, 2, 1
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    lados[i] =-lados[i];
}        
if(lados[0]>= lados[1]+lados[2]){
   System.out.println("NAO FORMA TRIANGULO");

}else if((lados[0]*lados[0]) == (lados[1]*lados[1])+(lados[2]*lados[2])){
    System.out.println("TRIANGULO RETANGULO");

}else if((lados[0]*lados[0])>(lados[1]*lados[1])+(lados[2]*lados[2])){
    System.out.println("TRIANGULO OBTUSANGULO");

}else if((lados[0]*lados[0])<(lados[1]*lados[1])+(lados[2]*lados[2])){
    System.out.println("TRIANGULO ACUTANGULO"); 

}

if(lados[0] >= lados[1]+lados[2]){

}else if( lados[0] == lados[1] && lados[0] == lados[2]){
    System.out.println("TRIANGULO EQUILATERO");

}else if(lados[0] == lados[1] || lados[1] == lados[2] || lados[2] == lados[0]){
    System.out.println("TRIANGULO ISOSCELES");
}else{
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Como vc só tem 3 valores, talvez seja mais simples fazer `if (a < b) { troca os valores de a e b }` e em seguida `if (a < c) { troca os valores de a e c}` (a troca é como vc já estava fazendo). Com isso vc já garante que `a` será maior que `b` e `c` (e nem precisa ordenar `b` e `c`, pois tanto faz a ordem destes, no seu caso).